# How can I see the startup logging of an embedded web application in my iphone simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I am debugging a web application with javascript (AngularJS) embedded inside an iPhone app. I'm pretty sure the angular app outputs some logging at startup, but I cannot figure out how I can access it.

Problem is that if I attach the web inspector from Safari to my iPhone simulator, it is already too late, because the app has already started.

How can I get to those logs?

Answer (score 0):

`document.location.reload();` does the trick just fine.